# springmvc display page issue

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I have been struggling for a while to set up an mvc project and it's been a while I have been trying to display the welcome.html page without any success.

[image: Below is the structure of the project]

Above is the structure of the project

My homecontroller

```
        /**
 * 
 */
package com.knockknocks.controller;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;

    /**
     * @author vimal
     *
     */
    @Controller

    public class HomeController {
        @RequestMapping(value="/welcome")
        public ModelAndView home(){
            String message = "This is your home";
            System.out.println(123456);
             return new ModelAndView("welcome", "message", message);
        }

    }
```

works-servlet.xml

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans     
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.knockknocks.controller" />
<mvc:annotation-driven />
    <bean id="viewResolver"
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.UrlBasedViewResolver">
        <property name="viewClass"
            value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView" />
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/" />
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </bean>

</beans>
```

web.xml

```
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">
  <display-name>Knockknocks</display-name>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>works</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>
            org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
        </servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>works</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/welcome.jsp</url-pattern>
    <url-pattern>/welcome.html</url-pattern>
    <url-pattern>*.html</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

pom file

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>KnockKnocks</groupId>
  <artifactId>KnockKnocks</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
  <build>
    <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.5</version>
        <configuration>
          <source>1.8</source>
          <target>1.8</target>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.6</version>
        <configuration>
          <warSourceDirectory>WebContent</warSourceDirectory>
          <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>


    </plugins>
  </build>
  <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>4.2.5.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
            <version>4.2.5.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>4.2.5.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            <version>4.2.5.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.3</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

Log

```
Apr 23, 2016 9:23:04 PM org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner scanJars
INFO: At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
Apr 23, 2016 9:23:05 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: No Spring WebApplicationInitializer types detected on classpath
Apr 23, 2016 9:23:05 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Initializing Spring FrameworkServlet 'works'
Apr 23, 2016 9:23:05 PM org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet initServletBean
INFO: FrameworkServlet 'works': initialization started
Apr 23, 2016 9:23:05 PM org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext prepareRefresh
INFO: Refreshing WebApplicationContext for namespace 'works-servlet': startup date [Sat Apr 23 21:23:05 MUT 2016]; root of context hierarchy
Apr 23, 2016 9:23:06 PM org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader loadBeanDefinitions
INFO: Loading XML bean definitions from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/works-servlet.xml]
Apr 23, 2016 9:23:10 PM org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet initServletBean
INFO: FrameworkServlet 'works': initialization completed in 5153 ms
Apr 23, 2016 9:23:10 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
Apr 23, 2016 9:23:10 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
Apr 23, 2016 9:23:10 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in 12093 ms
```

when i try accress the url http://localhost:8080/KnockKnocks/welcome.html, I have an error HTTP Status 404 - /KnockKnocks/welcome.html.

I would appreciate someone could help me out.

Regards

Comment: use value instead name in RequestMapping and test it .

Comment: I added value instead of name, I have same prob. See edit

Comment: question: why do  you have "sourceDirectory" in  your pom.xml? I'm not saying it's necessarily wrong. Just wondering what the purpose is and whether your problem has something to do with that.

Comment: The src folder specifies where all my source codes can be found. Anyway I tried removing it also and still facing the same prob

Comment: Looks like your pom.xml has an issue (see red 'x'). What is causing that? To find out, open the pom.xml and hover over the 'x'.

Comment: It says my maven repo is offline

Answer (score 2):

Use :

```
<mvc:annotation-driven />
```

in your works-servlet.xml

It'll sets your Spring context to allow for dispatching requests to Controllers.

I hope this helps you.

Answer (score 2):

Your sample *works.servlet* shows:

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.knockknock.controller" />
```

But the package shown in  your HomeController class is:

```
package com.knockknocks.controller;
```

You need those to match. The former is missing the 's'.

Comment: The version in `web.xml` is the servlet API version, not the Spring Framework version.

Answer (score 1):

Your class `HomeController` isn't mapping any url:

```
@Controller
public class HomeController {

    @RequestMapping(name = "/welcome")
    public ModelAndView home(){
        String message = "This is your home";
        return new ModelAndView("welcome", "message", message);
    }
}
```

You must change `@RequestMapping(name = "/welcome")` to `@RequestMapping(value = "/welcome")`.
As this [document](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html?is-external=true) has provided, option elements of `@RequestMapping` annotation:
`name: String` - Assign a name to this mapping.
`value: String[]` - The primary mapping expressed by this annotation.
...

Comment: I added value instead of name but I have same issue

Comment: You try to create a spring project (HelloWorld) from Spring Template in STS and run it, then rerun your project. I think this is solution although i don't know why.

Answer (score 1):

I've got another idea. Check that your .jsp is in the correct location and is named correctly. That is, do you have a welcome.jsp in your WEB-INF/jsp directory? Look also at the specific message on your 404 page to see what specific file it is not finding and check whether you really have that file in that directory location.